# PHP Intervention orientate() doesn't work for iphone

Tags: php, intervention

Uploading images doesn't work for iphones. Portrait images appear like landscape.

Tried to orientate before saving
Tried to pull the image again and orientate after saving.
Not working... Is it Intervention issues or something with my code?

```
img = Image::make($originalImage);          
$img->resize(150, null, function ($constraint) {
   $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$path = public_path() . "/thumbnails/";
$img->save($path . $photo_full_name);
Image::make($path . $photo_full_name)->orientate()->save($path . 
$photo_full_name);
```

Comment: Looks like you're [not the only one](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/906). Is your PHP [compiled with `--enable-exif`](http://image.intervention.io/api/orientate)?

Comment: yes, it's enabled

Comment: Just to double check EXIF support in PHP check the result of `extension_loaded('exif') && function_exists('exif_read_data')` is `true`.